# how to make slide out navigation like gmail from scratch?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, slide

I want to make slide out navigation like gmail, I actually can make that by following the tutorial from appcoda in here https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

but the tutorial uses `SWRevealViewController` pod to make the slide out navigation, it seems `SWRevealViewController`  no longer maintaned, and it will give more and more warning in the next update of swift version, it makes me worried.

so how to make slide out navigation like gmail  from scratch ? or is there any pod available that still maintained that can handle this? could you please share it to me ? I have tried to find, but I can't find one

Comment: You can use https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController/ or https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: https://github.com/kukushi/SideMenu